# Install TWRP/Lineage on Huawei 10 Mate Lite (RNE-L21) Oreo

Tags: twrp, huawei, lineageos

I'm trying to install TWRP to be able to get LineageOS running. 
But I'm stuck at the very first step:

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
$ fastboot flash recovery twrp8.img 
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'recovery' (18296 KB)...
OKAY [  0.757s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.763s
```

It seemed to be the issue that "OEM-Unlock active" had to be activated. Is done on my phone. I'm getting a white screen with some message, at the bottom written:

```
PHONE Locked (in green)
FRP Unlock (in red)
```

I've been trying to figure out how to unlock the phone and apparently there are ways to do that with `fastboot flashing lock`. The command fails.
Seems there was a time Huawei used to give away codes which allowed to unlock it.

I'm stuck now, are there options I forgot to enable? Or other ways?

I'm using using Linux and as stated in the Title:
Model: RNE-L21
EMUI: 8.0
Android: 8.0

Comment: If it is a rather new Huawei device, that might be a "deadlock" – as Huawei decided to no longer allow bootloader unlock.

Comment: @Izzy - how would I find out?

Comment: No idea. I've scrapped Huawei from my list when they announced that (about a year ago IIRC). [According to GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_mate_10_lite-8857.php), your device was first released 11/2017, which was around the time. Though [XDA has a guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mate-10/how-to/how-to-huawei-mate-10-pro-standard-t3709535), you'll fail at the first step: that Huawei link to obtain your unlock code no longer exists (it redirects to their "EMUI news" page). Bad luck I'm afraid. (PS: the XDA thread has some work-arounds for $4)

Comment: If your security patch level is newer than June 2018, then it has been patched against BL code obtaining tools, and you're out of luck.

Comment: @AndyYan - how do I find that out and what exactly is that security patch?

Comment: Didn't expect that you're still watching this question... It should be right there in the "about phone" page in Settings.

Comment: @AndyYan - why would I post a question and then just decide to ignore it? That patch was probably in the last security update... 5th of June 2019. Shit

Comment: Yeah, tough luck. Hate Huawei for the sudden betrayal.